# List creation in Erlang

Tags: list, erlang, reverse

From "Erlang Programming" by Cesarini exercise 3-2

As I go through "Erlang Programming" I get weird list creation issues.  From exercise 3-2 I wrote two similar functions.

```
create( 0 ) -> [];
create( N ) when N > 0 -> [ N | create( N-1 ) ].

reverse_create( 0 ) -> [];
reverse_create( N ) when N > 0 -> [ reverse_create( N-1 ) | N ].
```

so create(3) generates as I'd expect.

exercise3:create(3).        
[3,2,1]

but reverse_create does not generate the list I expect.

exercise3:reverse_create(3).
[[[[]|1]|2]|3]

What do I need to change so that reverse_create(3) returns [1,2,3]?  Thanks for explaining.

Comment: OK, got the example working.  Any clue why the two similar functions above return such different answers?  Why does create return a clean list while reverse_create returns lists of lists?

Comment: you can read this for explanation: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#lists and also look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232786/how-to-concat-lists-in-erlang-without-creating-nested-lists and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919097/functional-programming-what-is-an-improper-list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`reverse_create` returns a list and you using that as head element to create the list which is resulting in nested lists. Try this solution:

```
reverse_create( 0 ) -> [];
reverse_create( N ) when N > 0 -> reverse_create( N-1 ) ++ [N].
```

EDIT: A much better implementation would be:

```
reverse_create2(N) -> reverse_create_helper(N, []).

reverse_create_helper(0, Acc) ->
    Acc;
reverse_create_helper(N, Acc) ->
    reverse_create_helper(N-1, [N|Acc]).
```

Comment: It makes nice O(N^2) from O(N) task.

Comment: I have made the edits as you correctly pointed out since ++ copies the left operand.

Answer (score 3):

Normally a function such as reverse_create would be done in a tail-recursive fashion with an accumulator.

```
reverse_create(N) ->
    reverse_create(N, []).

reverse_create(0, Acc) ->
    Acc;
reverse_create(N, Acc) when N > 0 ->
    reverse_create(N - 1, [N | Acc]).
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you could always do:

```
reverse_create(N) -> lists:reverse(create(N)).
```

This would actually run faster. But that obviously isn't the intent of the exercise. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading the same book, so I'm no more expert than you, but this worked for me...

```
create(0) -> [];
create(N) when N > 0 -> create(N-1) ++ [N].

reverse_create(0) -> [];
reverse_create(N) when N > 0 -> [N|create(N-1)].
```

Answer (score 0):

This is

```
    reverse_create(0) -> [];
    reverse_create(N) ->
        list_create_1(1, N, []).

    list_create_1(I, N, List) when N >= I ->
        list_create_1(I + 1, N, [I | List]);
    list_create_1(_, _, List) -> List.
```